# Hadoop YARN clusters - Adding node at runtime

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I am working on a solution providing run-time ressources addition to an Hadoop Yarn cluster. The purpose is to handle heavy peaks on our application.

I am not an expert and I need help in order to approve / contest what I understand.

**Hadoop YARN**

This application an run in a cluster-mode. It provides ressource management (CPU & RAM).
A spark a application, for example, ask for a job to be done. Yarn handles the request and provides an executor computing on the Yarn cluster.

**HDFS - Data & Executors**

The datas are not shared through executors, so they have to be stored in a file System. In my case : HDFS. That means I will have to run a copy of my spark streaming application in the new server (hadoop node).

**I am not sure of this** :

The yarn cluster and HDFS are different, writing on HDFS won't write on the new hadoop node local data (because it is not an HDFS node).

As I will only write on HDFS new data from a spark streaming application, creating a new application should not be a problem.

1. Submit the job to yarn
   --- peak, resources needed
2. Instance new server
3. Install / configure Hadoop & YARN, making it a slave

   - Modifying hadoop/conf/slaves, adding it's ip adress (or dns name from host file)
   - Moddifying dfs.include and mapred.include

     On host machine :
   - yarn -refreshNodes
   - bin/hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes
   - bin/hadoop mradmin -refreshNodes

Should this work ? refreshQueues sounds not really useful here as it seems to only take care of the process queue.

I am not sure if the running job will increase it's capacity. Another idea is to wait for the new ressources to be available and submit a new job.

Thanks for you help

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but my suggestion would be to start reading "hadoop definitive guide" book. You are not getting most of hadoop concepts right